# Objects and Lists

Tags: python-2.7

I have a duck Class, such that each Duck object created contains wingspan and weight field variables. Each of these should be initialized randomly for every duck. Wingspans should be initialized to a random float in the range [80.0,100.0]cm. Weight should be initialized randomly in the range [0.7,1.6]kg. I have

```
import random
class Duck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.wingspan = round(random.uniform(80.0, 100.0), 1)
        self.weight = round(random.uniform(0.7,1.6), 2)
```

But the second part is asking me to write a function called makeFlock() that takes an integer parameter, n, and returns a list of n Duck objects. I'm not sure how to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Homework + no own effort => downvote :(

Answer (score 2):

```
def makeFlock(n):
    flock = []
    for _ in range(n):
        flock.append(Duck())
    return(flock)
```